# How hardware acceleration can be disabled in WPF?

Tags: wpf, hardware-acceleration

What is the procedure for disabling hardware acceleration in WPF? What is it exactly? Is it a Windows setting, a Visual Studio setting, or something you alter in the code of your WPF project? Will it affect only the program you're running or will it be system-wide?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Software rendering mode - WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951058/software-rendering-mode-wpf)

Answer (score -9, accepted):

That is a system wide setting, from the desktop, right click to bring up a popup menu, click on properties, and look around in there for the video settings to disable Hardware acceleration or that there may be a system tray icon for the graphics settings. This is system wide and not local.

Comment: Note this disables ALL hardware graphics acceleration in the system, not just WPF.

Comment: This is not available in most systems, as both nVidia and Ati do not allow you to disable (or even alter) the hardware acceleration as long as their drivers are installed. @itowlson has the correct answer to this.

Comment: Agree with @itowlson. This disables all hardware acceleration when WPF alone can be disabled mentioned below

Answer (score 47):

You can disable it on a `Window` level starting from .Net 3.5 SP1.

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    public MyWindow()
        : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        var hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;

        if (hwndSource != null)
            hwndSource.CompositionTarget.RenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;

        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    }
}
```

or you can subscribe to `SourceInitialized` event of the window and do the same.

Alternatively you can [set it on Process level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.processrendermode.aspx):

```
RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

The precedence order for software rendering is:

1. DisableHWAcceleration registry key
2. ProcessRenderMode
3. RenderMode (per-target)

Answer (score 25):

It is a machine-wide registry setting.  See [Graphics Rendering Registry Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970912%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the WPF docs for the registry key and other details relating to customizing WPF rendering.

The key listed is:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\DisableHWAcceleration`

The MSDN document is "not available" for .NET 4.5, so this may be a depricated option that only works in 4.0 or below.

Comment: _[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_

Comment: It's far better to just disable it for YOUR app. See the other answer by Konstantin

Comment: @WarrenP Certainly, but sometimes you're dealing with a broken program or just you don't have access to the code, the registry becomes a last resort.

Comment: Another, I think newer link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/graphics-rendering-registry-settings

Answer (score 16):

In version 4.0, you can also use `RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode` to set a process wide preference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.processrendermode.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can also disble hardware acceleration in WPF App by adding in MainWindow the following code.

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    var hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;

    if (hwndSource != null)
        hwndSource.CompositionTarget.RenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;

    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
}
```

This solved my issue with TeamViewer.

Source:
[How does one disable hardware acceleration in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169600/how-does-one-disable-hardware-acceleration-in-wpf?msclkid=78ee2f7ad14f11eca936ed88fd09471b)