# Broken GUI Rendering with nVIDIA 320M GPU on Windows 10

Tags: windows, user-interface, rendering, direct3d

My laptop computer is MacBook Pro 13" 2010-mid with nVIDIA 320M GPU. My OS is Windows 10 x64 ver 1607. The nVIDIA driver version is 341.98.
I meet a broken GUI rendering problem. See the screenshot of Visual Studio 2017 RC GUI:
[image]
You can see the Solution Explorer pane in the left shows a broken rendering.
Actually, there are not only Visual Studio GUI, but also many application GUIs have the same broken rendering problem, for example, JabRef, Atlassian SourceTree, ...
And, there are not only Windows 10 but also Windows 8 having the same problem. Does anyone have a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find workarounds for several my frequently-used apps. These workarounds show the problem comes from the GPU hardware acceleration. Disable the acceleration for working around the broken rendering problem.

For Java apps (e.g., JabRef), the workaround is to set environment variable J2D_D3D to false. See: 
[Swing rendering appears broken in JDK 1.8, correct in JDK 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7)

For Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) apps (e.g., SourceTree and Visual Studio 2017 RC), the workaround is to disable WPF acceleration by adding a registry value:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\DisableHWAcceleration
with data "1." See: 
[How does one disable hardware acceleration in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169600/how-does-one-disable-hardware-acceleration-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

i had many problems with windows 10 on MBP Pro mid2010, i resolved all my problems by installing the upgrade to Build 1909 by downloading the upgrade utility:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
after that i installed BootCamp4.0.4033 and by magic all works fine.